# How to get malformed JSON in Retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am sending a request, but I am getting an exception, even though the request is successful(The API I am interacting with, sends an OTP on success).

The exception is:

```
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 2 path $
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1573)
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1423)
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:575)
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:429)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.read(TypeAdapters.java:349)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.read(TypeAdapters.java:346)
            at com.google.gson.TypeAdapter.fromJson(TypeAdapter.java:256)
            at retrofit.GsonConverter.fromBody(GsonConverter.java:42)
            at retrofit.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:144)
            at retrofit.OkHttpCall.access$000(OkHttpCall.java:25)
            at retrofit.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:90)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:168)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Now how would I see that malformed JSON? In order to know if what Json object is malformed, if it is the object being returned(which I am expecting to be a string) , or is it the object That I am sending.

Forgive me if this is a trivial question, I only started with Android development, as of this week.

Here is the service:

```
public static EnrollmentApiInterface getApiClient(){
    if (EnrollmentRequest == null) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

                Request request = chain.request();
                Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
                request.body().writeTo(buffer);
                String body = buffer.readUtf8();
                Log.println(10, TAG, body);
                Log.i(TAG, "hello:        " + response);

                String bodyString = response.body().string();
                Log.i(TAG, bodyString);
                response = response.newBuilder()
                    .body(ResponseBody.create(response.body().contentType(), bodyString))
                    .build();
                return response;
            }
        });

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            // .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:6543/") // On AVD
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.106:6543") // On device
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

        EnrollmentRequest = retrofit.create(EnrollmentApiInterface.class);
    }
    return EnrollmentRequest;
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface EnrollmentApiInterface {

        @Headers({
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-Type: application/json"
        })
        @POST("auth/enroll")
        Call<String> RequestEnrollment(@Body JsonObject EnrollmentDetails);

        @Headers({
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-Type: application/json"
        })
        @POST("auth/enroll/auth")
        Call<String> AuthoriseEnrollment(@Body JsonObject LoginDetails);


    }
}
```

and here is the call:

```
EnrollmentRequest request = new EnrollmentRequest();
    request.setMsisdn(MsisdnTxt.getText().toString());
    request.setId_number(IdNumberTxt.getText().toString());
    EnrollmentApiClient.EnrollmentApiInterface service = EnrollmentApiClient.getApiClient();
    Log.i(TAG, "REQUEST:   " + request.toJson());
    Call<String> call = service.RequestEnrollment(request.toJson());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<String> response) {
            Log.i(TAG, "ON RESPONSE" + response);
            Log.i(TAG, "ON RESPONSE BODY" + response.body());
            // Create object of SharedPreferences.
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(that);
            //now get Editor
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            //put your value
            editor.putString("IDnumber", IdNumberTxt.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("Msisdn", MsisdnTxt.getText().toString());

            //commits your edits
            editor.commit();
            Log.i(TAG, "onClick-AFTER");
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AuthoriseActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            // It always comes in here
            Log.i(TAG, "NOTHERE", t);
            Log.d("CallBack", " Throwable is " + t.toString());

            Toast.makeText(EnrollActivity.this, "Request Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
```

Comment: Hello retrofit beta-2 has released which has retrofit parameter along with response which will help you view raw data as response. 

Your problem is response sent from server is not in valid format.
You can create your own gsonConverter, pass in your adapter and inside you can see the response from server converting it as string.

Comment: @subhash I did add a string converter, because I am expecting the response to be a string, but I still get the same error. any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just log your network responses, so you will see what's wrong.

```
@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
    Log.w("Retrofit@Response", response.body().string());
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Where would I put this?  at the moment it is in my `getApiClient` method, but it is not logging anything(I suspect it might not be calling it). Do I need to call it? if so where?

Comment: You have to set your `OkHttpClient` in `Retrofit.Builder` using `client` method.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use string convertor to Retrofit restadapter

```
 RestAdapter adapterRfqPost = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(Constants.ENDPOINT)
                    .setConverter(new ConstantsMethods.StringConverter())
                    .build();
```

---

String converter class

```
public static class StringConverter implements Converter {
        @Override
        public Object fromBody(TypedInput typedInput, Type type) throws ConversionException {
            String text = null;
            try {
                text = fromStream(typedInput.in());
            } catch (IOException ignored) {/*NOP*/ }
            return text;
        }

        @Override
        public TypedOutput toBody(Object o) {
            return null;
        }



 public static String fromStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
            out.append(newLine);`enter code here`
            }`enter code here`
            return out.toString();
        }
    }
```